# Terminal on Mac Error: .zshrc:export:8: not valid in this context: -v

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos

Getting this error whenever I start up Terminal on my Mac:

```
.zshrc:export:8: not valid in this context: -v
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Last semester I tried to download HomeBrew on my Mac for a class but ran into some problems, resulting in the error.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70289451/zshrcexport2-not-valid-in-this-context-terminal-not-working-macos-big-sur-af

Comment: Check line 8 of your `~/.zshrc`. There's probably something that does `export something ... -v`... Try also running `zsh -x ~/.zshrc`